# Reusing a stream when extra filtering is needed - Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, audit

The following code, in summary, is mean to filter through the first parameter for entities that are in the second parameter. And if a 'change' was specified in the second parameter, it should filter a narrower result.
When I run this I get an error of 'IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed.' 
Is there a way that I can reuse the same stream?
 
I have seen people implementing something like Supplier>, but I don't think that would work for this case. Or, I'm just not familiar enough with it to understand how I could use Supplier.

```
/**
     * Filters through DocumentAuditEntityListing to find existence of the entities
     * ActionEnum, ActionContextEnum, LevelEnum, & StatusEnum.
     *
     * @param audits A list of audits to search
     * @param toFind The audit entities to find
     * @return If entities found, return DocumentAudit, else null
     */
    public DocumentAudit verifyAudit(DocumentAuditEntityListing audits, DocumentAudit toFind) {
        //Filter for proper entities
        Stream stream = audits.getEntities().stream().filter(doc -> (
                doc.getAction().equals(toFind.getAction())) &&
                doc.getActionContext().equals(toFind.getActionContext()) &&
                doc.getLevel().equals(toFind.getLevel()) &&
                doc.getStatus().equals(toFind.getStatus()));

        //If changes were specified, filter further.
        if (toFind.getChanges() != null){
            stream.filter(change -> (toFind.getChanges().contains(change)));
        }

        return (DocumentAudit) stream.findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
```

Comment: Streams have terminal and non-terminal methods. Non-terminal methods like map and filter are lazy, meaning they don't actually do anything until a terminal method is called. This means that you just need to "append" to the Stream by adding the filter as explained by @Kayaman, but you aren't "re-using" the stream because it hasn't been "used" until you call `findFirst().orElse(null)`

Comment: good question, not that trivial to understand from the error message indeed. essentially your are *consuming* your stream only once, but that is not what the error message is saying... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548077/1059372

Answer (score 7):

You need to assign the resulting stream with `stream = stream.filter(change -> ...)`.

Also make the stream typesafe (i.e. `Stream<DocumentAudit>`). Generics have been around since Java 5, so you don't have an excuse to use raw types.

```
        Stream<DocumentAudio> stream = audits.getEntities().stream()
            .filter(doc -> 
                doc.getAction().equals(toFind.getAction())) &&
                doc.getActionContext().equals(toFind.getActionContext()) &&
                doc.getLevel().equals(toFind.getLevel()) &&
                doc.getStatus().equals(toFind.getStatus());


        if (toFind.getChanges() != null){
            stream = stream.filter(change -> toFind.getChanges().contains(change));
        }

        return stream.findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Supplier` is not a *trick*, but simply used to facilitate the creation of a new stream. The rule is is still the same - you can not reuse a stream, under no circumstances. The general approach of using the `Supplier` is something like this:

```
 Supplier<Stream<Something>>  sup = () -> yourList.stream();
```

So every time you call `sup.get()` you are getting a new `Stream`. There is nothing fancy in this, just a matter of style.

Actually your question is a bit different then the ones I have already seen like this. Basically you are doing:

```
Stream<Some> s = ...

s.filter
s.filter
s.forEach
```

And I find the error message a bit misleading here, what `stream has already been operated upon or closed` means is actually that a *single* terminal *or* intermediate operation can be applied only once to a single `Stream`. If this would have been more clear in the error message it would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is confusing, because the stream is not being reused (only one terminal operation is being called, which is `findFirst()`).

However, as pointed out by others, the application of `stream.filter(...)` within the `if` block is being lost, because the stream returned by that `filter` operation is never asigned to a variable. This is the cause of such confusing error.

Despite all this, I would like to show you another way to deal with this requirement. Instead of conditionally applying an extra filter, you could work on the predicate first and then, once ready, pass it to the `stream.filter(...)` operation:

```
Predicate<DocumentAudit> pred = doc ->
    doc.getAction().equals(toFind.getAction()) &&
    doc.getActionContext().equals(toFind.getActionContext()) &&
    doc.getLevel().equals(toFind.getLevel()) &&
    doc.getStatus().equals(toFind.getStatus());

// If changes were specified, filter further.
if (toFind.getChanges() != null) {
    pred = pred.and(change -> toFind.getChanges().contains(change));
}

return audits.getEntities().stream()
    .filter(pred)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

Some comments...

I've used [`Predicate.and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) to compose the conditions.

You were using a raw stream and casting in the last line. Please don't do that anymore. We are on 2017...

Ideally, you should use `Optional` as the returning value of your method (instead of returning either the found object or `null`). This way, users of your method would know in advance that the object might either have been found or not. And they could even use `Optional`'s handy operations to conditionally perform actions over the object, or conditionally map it to some of its attributes, etc.